# How to overplot concatenated data from different Lon/Lat frames on a single map (python2.7)?

Tags: python-2.7, concatenation, interpolation, matplotlib-basemap

This is my first request here. I'm not very familiar with Python and I'll do my best to be understood.(Native French ;))

I'm currently working on several NetCDF files containing altimetric data.
For each NetCDF file, I'm plotting the satellite along-track with basemap, according lon/lat arrays, that differ for each file (i.e for each track).

[Track 70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km8Rl.png)

[Track 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZzpE.png)

I'm trying to plot all these tracks on a single map. So I've concatenated all NetCDF files and get these dimensions for all variables: (Ntracks, Npoints, Ncycles).

I'd like to keep lon/lat arrays of the first track to plot all tracks onto the map. Previously in the code, I have been doing a loop over the number of cycles to get lon/lat arrays with only two dimensions (Ntracks, Npoints)

```
# Define map
m = Basemap(projection='mill',lat_ts=10,\
            llcrnrlon= lon[0,:].min(), \
            urcrnrlon= lon[0,:].max(), \
            llcrnrlat= lat[0,:].min(), \
            urcrnrlat= lat[0,:].max(), \
            resolution='l')

# Area 
lonmin, lonmax = m.lonmin, m.lonmax
latmin, latmax = m.latmin, m.latmax       
print lonmin, lonmax
print latmin, latmax 

# Dimensions
Ntracks, Npoints, Ncycles = data.shape

for track in range(Ntracks):
  print 'file', track, 'track', Tracks[track]    
  x, y = np.meshgrid( lon[track,:], lat[track,:] )
  y = y.T

  for c in range(Ncycles): 
    Data, tmp = m(*np.meshgrid( data[track,:,c], lon[0,:] ))

    # plot Data on the map
    # m.contourf(x, y, Data)

    # plot Track position on the map
    m.plot(x, y, marker= 'o', markersize= 3, color= '#1e90ff', markeredgecolor='#1e90ff')

parallels = np.arange( 45.   , latmax, 5., dtype= 'int')
meridians = np.arange( lonmin, lonmax, 5., dtype= 'int')

[...]
```

Here is my problem:

1) Do I have to use an interpolation function from basemap ?

Here I'm just using the *meshgrid* function to plot the data, but it does not work apparently, and I use it with an array I do not need and inside a loop... I'd like to loop over the number of tracks (Ntracks) and the number of cycles (Ncycles) to keep all the information contained in data array, but nothing is displayed on the map.

2)

I've got a map with uncorrect lon/lat frame, in the sense that I'm forcing in the code the parallels to start at 45°N in latitude and it shows latitudes starting at 0° (see map below).

**[EDIT 1]**

```
Here is the zone for which all tracks should be plotted onto:

lonmin= -17.9882926941   
lonmax= 4.60782623291
latmin= 45.              
latmax= 60.7448616028

file 0 track 011

Lon(Ntracks, Npoints)  <=> Lon(39, 600) 

lon[0,:]=
[-17.98829269 -17.96035004 -17.9158268  -17.87090111 -17.82613754
 -17.78137589 -17.73649788 -17.69123077 -17.64610481 -17.60084343
 -17.55563354 -17.51044273 -17.4653244  -17.41967773 -17.37390709
 -17.32869911 -17.28360939 -17.23790359 -17.19250679 -17.14686203
 -17.10056877 -17.05456734 -17.00789261 -16.96157265 -16.91489029
 -16.86802864 -16.82170677 -16.77542496 -16.72836304 -16.68114853
 -16.63401222 -16.58691406 -16.54015732 -16.49285126 -16.44582558
 -16.39826965 -16.35064316 -16.3035717  -16.25635719 -16.20870781
 -16.16150856 -16.1133728  -16.06542015 -16.01705933 -15.96865177
 -15.92026043 -15.87177563 -15.82310295 -15.77482033 -15.72598553
 -15.67701912 -15.62811565 -15.57882786 -15.53001785 -15.48101044
 -15.43181229 -15.38246822 -15.33287716 -15.28355789 -15.23418236
 -15.18494129 -15.13527107 -15.0858717  -15.03561592 -14.98551655
 -14.93518257 -14.88439083 -14.83401299 -14.78322983 -14.73276806
 -14.68206596 -14.6312542  -14.58057022 -14.52875805 -14.47770214
 -14.4268198  -14.37572861 -14.32432938 -14.27313328 -14.22089672
 -14.16933823 -14.11782074 -14.06633949 -14.01482773 -13.96279335
 -13.91062164 -13.8580122  -13.80557537 -13.75274754 -13.70005322
 -13.64694786 -13.59441757 -13.54134083 -13.48770905 -13.43468666
 -13.38124275 -13.32789707 -13.27467823 -13.22168827 -13.16738701
 -13.11308289 -13.05891991 -13.00494385 -12.95111179 -12.89686108
 -12.84276581 -12.78821468 -12.7339344  -12.67910194 -12.62386894
 -12.56842422 -12.51327515 -12.45816803 -12.40354824 -12.34745026
 -12.29209328 -12.23564339 -12.18034649 -12.12487125 -12.06906986
 -12.01329899 -11.95672607 -11.8996048  -11.843297   -11.78651047
 -11.73054409 -11.67354107 -11.61672497 -11.56000042 -11.50267315
 -11.44525433 -11.38746643 -11.32937717 -11.27204227 -11.21484566
 -11.15631771 -11.0982399  -11.0397234  -10.98154163 -10.92320538
 -10.86515236 -10.80695057 -10.7475996  -10.68784046 -10.62869835
 -10.56943226 -10.51098156 -10.45191383 -10.392416   -10.33296585
 -10.27302551 -10.21626282 -10.16596699  -7.04195881  -6.97156954
  -6.90749311  -6.84037924  -6.77310753  -6.70632839  -6.64275551
  -6.5768404   -2.65448499  -2.58824921  -2.51378822  -2.43802571
  -2.36123848  -2.2846365   -2.20791101  -2.13056469  -2.05158925
  -1.97271824  -1.89305627  -1.81484437  -1.73559391  -1.65574718
  -1.57778573  -1.49864793  -1.41998756  -1.33994663  -1.25909233
  -1.17918336  -1.09941947  -1.01876879  -0.93915391  -0.85877413
  -0.77846903  -0.6969139   -0.61503422  -0.53209156  -0.45091194
  -0.36821485  -0.28601661  -0.20424061  -0.12195258  -0.03996643
   0.0433232    0.12745281   0.21068352   0.29375839   0.37731969
   0.46031842   0.54389882   0.62750047   0.71277285   0.79772025
   0.88338596   0.9679296    1.05336332   1.13906097   1.22359383
   1.30949378   1.39461899   1.4820528    1.56847286   1.65480137
   1.7418288    1.82818389   1.9145112    2.00085664   2.08809233
   2.17680693   2.26604605   2.35390067   2.44224119   2.53127289
   2.6189208    2.70771909   2.79608703   2.88613439   2.97592211
   3.06579161   3.15590477   3.24528027   3.33474064   3.42422748
   3.51482105   3.60685039   3.69885063   3.78991985   3.88147163
   3.97312284   4.06450033   4.15607595   4.24770594   4.34134626
   4.43407822   4.52639294   4.60782623   0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]

Lat(Ntracks, Npoints) <=> Lat(39, 600)
lat[0,:]=
[ 46.67876053  46.70789719  46.75389481  46.80019379  46.84618378
  46.89203644  46.93796539  46.98420334  47.03012466  47.07610321
  47.12192535  47.16764069  47.21319199  47.25907135  47.30500793
  47.35031509  47.39530945  47.44083023  47.48605728  47.531353
  47.57711792  47.62258148  47.66851807  47.71405792  47.75978851
  47.80570221  47.85082626  47.89584732  47.94157028  47.98722076
  48.03278732  48.07815552  48.12312698  48.16848373  48.21348572
  48.25885773  48.30422974  48.34898376  48.39368439  48.43871307
  48.483181    48.52843857  48.57341003  48.61867523  48.66384888
  48.70891953  48.75396347  48.79903793  48.84369659  48.88874817
  48.93371582  48.97858047  49.02370453  49.06818771  49.11281586
  49.1574707   49.20219421  49.2469635   49.29138947  49.33580399
  49.37992096  49.42437744  49.46848297  49.51322556  49.55770111
  49.60223007  49.64704132  49.69140244  49.73606491  49.78027344
  49.82453156  49.86888885  49.91291809  49.95780563  50.00203705
  50.04593658  50.08992004  50.13394165  50.17778397  50.22238159
  50.26634979  50.31006622  50.35368347  50.39723587  50.44110489
  50.4848938   50.52896881  50.57278061  50.61688232  50.66064072
  50.70475006  50.74821472  50.79191589  50.8360405   50.87957764
  50.92328644  50.96680832  51.0102005   51.05315399  51.09710693
  51.14103317  51.18455505  51.2278862   51.27103043  51.31438446
  51.35745621  51.40075684  51.44378281  51.48701477  51.53056335
  51.57411957  51.61739731  51.6603775   51.70298004  51.74655151
  51.78942108  51.8330307   51.87560654  51.91830826  51.96100998
  52.003685    52.04676819  52.09022903  52.13286972  52.17581177
  52.21800613  52.26076508  52.30334854  52.34573364  52.38841248
  52.43110657  52.47396469  52.51687622  52.55908966  52.6010704
  52.64397049  52.68639755  52.72896576  52.77127838  52.81345749
  52.85536957  52.89732742  52.93992615  52.98266983  53.02484894
  53.06702805  53.10857391  53.15029907  53.19232941  53.23413849
  53.27612686  53.31597137  53.35136032  55.36987305  55.41225815
  55.45026016  55.49019241  55.52997208  55.56932831  55.60702133
  55.64598083  57.74236298  57.77462387  57.81058502  57.84719086
  57.88407516  57.92087173  57.95750427  57.99436951  58.03178406
  58.06901169  58.10655212  58.14322662  58.18028259  58.217453
  58.25369263  58.29024124  58.32647324  58.36317825  58.40009689
  58.43651962  58.47273254  58.50924683  58.5450325   58.58111572
  58.61699295  58.6533699   58.68965149  58.72631073  58.76209259
  58.79837036  58.8342247   58.86991501  58.9055748   58.94097137
  58.97681808  59.01285934  59.04847336  59.08379364  59.11923218
  59.15425873  59.18941879  59.22439575  59.26002884  59.29529953
  59.33084106  59.36565399  59.40074921  59.4357872   59.47022247
  59.50508499  59.53953552  59.57476807  59.60944366  59.64393997
  59.67856216  59.71277618  59.74685669  59.78082275  59.81495667
  59.84958267  59.88422775  59.91826248  59.95224762  59.98641968
  60.01992798  60.05369949  60.08721161  60.12124252  60.15496445
  60.18862534  60.22219467  60.25540161  60.28845596  60.32141876
  60.35464859  60.38824463  60.42168808  60.45466614  60.48766327
  60.52061844  60.55331039  60.58587646  60.61832047  60.65141296
  60.68397141  60.71630478  60.7448616    0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]

Data(Ntracks, Npoints, Ncycles) <=> Data(39, 600, 841)

data[0,:,0]=
[-- 60.757530212402344 60.614707946777344 60.51324462890625
 60.4495735168457 60.375301361083984 60.32353973388672 60.32004165649414
 60.300262451171875 60.279476165771484 60.23453903198242 60.14611053466797
 60.10492706298828 60.11872100830078 60.010215759277344 60.01679992675781
 60.02739334106445 60.066802978515625 59.99708938598633 59.957611083984375
 59.90860366821289 59.859092712402344 59.797611236572266 59.82122802734375
 59.76555252075195 59.80582809448242 59.78395462036133 59.772483825683594
 59.69769287109375 59.66111373901367 59.69377136230469 59.59833526611328
 59.56122970581055 59.4196662902832 59.33363342285156 -- 59.148193359375
 59.139976501464844 59.07219314575195 59.00056838989258 58.96044158935547
 58.793479919433594 58.71685028076172 58.660919189453125 58.6155891418457
 58.58014678955078 58.54222106933594 58.41620635986328 58.34292221069336
 58.252777099609375 58.19034957885742 58.19147872924805 58.04945755004883
 57.993141174316406 57.881595611572266 57.75284194946289 57.673988342285156
 57.546085357666016 57.44636917114258 57.33456802368164 57.22673034667969
 57.17810821533203 57.060855865478516 56.996437072753906 56.93328094482422
 56.91613006591797 56.93352508544922 56.90220260620117 56.9296760559082
 56.91029739379883 56.85015106201172 56.861961364746094 56.836082458496094
 56.787139892578125 56.74370574951172 56.63985824584961 56.602230072021484
 56.52391052246094 56.51660919189453 56.583072662353516 56.68135070800781
 56.87864685058594 57.20947265625 57.535404205322266 57.839866638183594
 58.04792785644531 58.211509704589844 58.28927230834961 58.30498123168945
 58.34526824951172 58.36879348754883 58.385929107666016 58.426536560058594
 58.49345779418945 58.57032012939453 58.644989013671875 58.690040588378906
 58.773582458496094 58.865699768066406 58.99164581298828 59.110862731933594
 59.230987548828125 59.282142639160156 59.38497543334961 59.463314056396484
 59.49340057373047 59.626068115234375 59.69114303588867 59.858642578125
 59.95542526245117 59.99937057495117 60.070919036865234 60.03804016113281
 59.97809600830078 59.87148666381836 59.790035247802734 --
 59.65596389770508 59.62194061279297 59.55290603637695 59.620635986328125
 59.64723587036133 59.79397201538086 59.94666290283203 60.14747619628906
 60.29004669189453 60.43260955810547 60.56108856201172 60.61063003540039
 60.656070709228516 60.633262634277344 60.578800201416016 60.46556091308594
 60.39137268066406 60.31590270996094 60.23550033569336 60.143409729003906
 60.12107467651367 60.056251525878906 59.99232864379883 59.92224884033203
 59.85647201538086 59.7867317199707 59.73897933959961 59.61933517456055
 59.55458068847656 59.484127044677734 59.402469635009766 59.34931945800781
 59.20806121826172 59.122562408447266 58.91756057739258 -- -- -- -- -- --
 56.795066833496094 56.77033996582031 56.6777229309082 -- -- -- -- -- --
 49.40351486206055 49.361656188964844 49.281063079833984 49.14778137207031
 49.10255813598633 49.08881378173828 49.0178337097168 49.016841888427734
 49.01139450073242 49.05029296875 49.02135467529297 49.01438522338867
 48.99295425415039 48.902462005615234 48.83680725097656 48.740150451660156
 48.63616943359375 48.580101013183594 48.51719284057617 48.39471435546875
 48.1739616394043 47.9736213684082 47.780086517333984 47.58523941040039
 47.404056549072266 47.18346405029297 47.02470397949219 46.925045013427734
 46.82598114013672 46.70199203491211 46.732479095458984 46.74734878540039
 46.783023834228516 46.78947448730469 46.713375091552734 46.77571105957031
 46.73973846435547 46.72625732421875 46.674217224121094 46.656429290771484
 46.73429489135742 46.767398834228516 46.6992301940918 46.69961929321289
 46.61093521118164 46.63847351074219 46.60043716430664 46.61210632324219
 46.60145568847656 46.54708480834961 46.542999267578125 46.46186828613281
 46.31348419189453 46.2059326171875 46.15165710449219 46.089412689208984
 46.001495361328125 45.91263961791992 45.77867126464844 45.679054260253906
 45.52286148071289 45.441471099853516 45.2866325378418 45.193050384521484
 45.02134704589844 44.91787338256836 44.865013122558594 44.81865692138672
 44.69915771484375 44.725948333740234 44.68387222290039 44.63495635986328
 44.725196838378906 44.79462432861328 44.785888671875 44.75141525268555
 44.883846282958984 44.94137191772461 45.078712463378906 45.230037689208984
 45.407440185546875 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
```

Comment: m.plot(...) should be outside the loop over the number of cycles.

Comment: Note that the colorbar is useless in this case, I'm just trying to plot the tracks, not the data for instance.

Comment: Can you show a, minimal, example of ```data```, ```lat```, and ```lon``` - and explain what each dimension *is*?

Comment: ```m.plot(x, y, ...``` - this looks like you are plotting the meshgrid coordinates, Not your lat/lon data.

Comment: ```m.plot(x, y, ...``` - the ```x``` and ```y``` arguments should be longitude and latitude vectors/arrays for a single track - [Basemap.plot](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.plot).

Comment: Try to simplify - instead of trying to do all of it, isolate lon/lat vectors for single track and see if you can plot it with ```m.plot()```, maybe in a separate file or at a shell prompt. -can you plot a single track?

Comment: I created arrays with fixed dimensions [Ntracks, Npoints, Ncycles]  - corresponding to the maximum values I could find when spanning all netcdf files - to broadcast arrays from each Netcdf file into the concatenated one (cause dimensions change for each netcdf file).

Comment: Yes you're right, when using m.plot(x, y, ...) I'm plotting projections coordinates of lon/lat arrays, not lon/lat arrays. But meshgrid transforms lon/lat 1D-arrays into 2D-arrays. So I thought I could use meshgrid for the 1D data array to be able to use contourf.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to specify the the map object "m" when using meshgrid ...

```
for track in range(Ntracks):

  x, y = m(*np.meshgrid( lon[track,:], lat[track,:] ))
  y = y.T

  m.plot(x, y, marker= '.')
```

This code allows me to plot lon/lat coordinates on the map, corresponding to the tracks locations.